# Celery is not executing tasks concurrently

Tags: python, django, redis, celery

**I'm new to celery, please let me know in comments if more information is required.**

I have around 3000 tasks queued in redis and i want to execute these tasks concurrently over multiple threads, after a bit of research i ended up using eventlet for thread pooling and set concurrency to 500, like so

```
celery worker -A <app_name> -P eventlet -c 500
```

but when i checked celery flower many free threads are available which the celery is not using
[image]

Any idea on how to make use of those free threads and make tasks faster?
also if possible please suggest a good read for working with celery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of those threads will run 500 eventlets. If your 3000 tasks are short-lived, they will be done with their work very fast. On top of that, your prefetch count is 400, which means while your worker (thread) runs 500 coroutines, it will also have 400 prefetched tasks. 3 * (500 + 400) = 2700 tasks will be taken from the queue immediately, assuming all your workers were idle.

Comment: oh, but the tasks seem to be running late.... The task which i am pushing to the queue is only getting executed after about 2 minutes, and it takes around 10-12 seconds for each task to complete.

Comment: Some of them (prefetched and those 300 left) will run later as there are not enough eventlet coroutines to run them all at once... If you add 1 more node to your Celery cluster you will be able, assuming they are completely idle, to run all 3000 tasks at once.